# What is to the word subside as procession is to that of proceed

Tags: verbs, nouns, vocabulary

What is the noun form of "subside"?

> The process of a migraine subsiding could be called the migraine's ___

Comment: Hi, J., welcome to ELU. I'm having a hard time understanding your sentence, is "valid" the word you meant to write?

Comment: This must be homework?

Comment: Azor, no. It was meant to be called. Apologies, I'm on a smartphone. And xanne, no, in fact it is not. Just a word I wanted to use but couldn't find in an email to an acquaintance.

Comment: You'd use the _ing_-form, 'subsiding'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Subsidence](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/subsidence)

/səbˈsaɪdəns; ˈsʌbsɪdəns/
noun
1.
the act or process of subsiding or the condition of having subsided
2.
(geology) the gradual sinking of landforms to a lower level as a result of earth movements, mining operations, etc

Unfortunately the rest of your sentence doesn't make much sense as written. Maybe you mean "the process of the migraine subsiding could be **described as** the migraine's subsidence."?

Comment: +1 I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted, although I do recommend that you include the linked definition in your answer here, for one-stop shopping convenience. In any case, you provided documentation for your answer and responded quite reasonably to the OP's question.

Comment: What's the synthesis on subsiding vs subsidence? Is it the subsidence of ones migraines, or their subsiding?